# Basic info such as first_name, etc - is marked as requiring no access token, but PHP SDK still can't get it

Tags: php, exception, facebook-php-sdk, access-token

This question may sound weird, but it's first time I do it and cannot find the answer to this. So why if some fields are marked as requiring **no access token**, I still get `"An active access token must be used to query information about the current user."` exception when I ask for them through PHP SDK from my App?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't know who the current user is if they haven't approved your app. So without an access_token you can call for example `graph.facebook.com/4` and get Zuckerberg's info, but you can't get call `graph.facebook.com/me`, because that's the whole point of getting permissions from users.